# given just an IP address calculate an IPTABLES DROP statement

Tags: iptables

I have a serious brain block on understanding this topic.

The short story.

I log botnet access to a server with 500 domains. 
For example, lots of bots look for WordPress sites.
I log when I generate a 404, I have thousands of these a day. 
I generate a report of the top offenders with the IP address from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and want to block them.
I know that the bots can change the address they use, but, I am guided by this principle, even the weakest link in your security toolset might be helpful

The fields in my log are as follows

DateStamp, 404, a flag I use for further analysis , URL_String, ServerName Constant, URL, remote ip constant, BAD_IP from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

```
Example log report entries


2020-03-02 00:09:24,404,1,Wp-content/plugins,SERVER_NAME,ablog1.com,remote ip,163.172.116.48
2020-03-02 00:09:48,404,1,page,SERVER_NAME,www.abloganother.com,remote ip,5.9.77.102
2020-03-02 00:09:50,404,1,Wp-loginphp/index,SERVER_NAME,athirdblogcom,remote ip,165.227.7.157

I want to generate IPTABLES rules for the worst offenders

Example

iptables -A INPUT -s 163.172.116.48/24 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 5.9.77.102/24 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 165.227.7.157/24 -j DROP
```

The slash /24 is just a guess. I want to know either a PHP or other set of functions I can call to generate the CIDR for a given IP address

However, I am unable to really understand what the CIDR stands for.
I have looked at iptab and ipcalc. I have looked at tools like this: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

I am still confused.

1 option I have is to generate the CDIR when I log the 404,
If I knew how to write the calcs for the CDIR
I would just calculate it by writing a function called calc_CDIR($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

2) I would gladly use any other calculation program , function etc.

But alas, I do not even now how to validate it. here is a snipet where I write to the log when I show a 404

```
if ($log_error)
{
if(!empty($page)) {
$msg1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ',404,1,'. $page . ',SERVER_NAME,' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .',remote ip,' . (string)$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(!error_log( $msg1. "\n", 3, $The404s)) {
log_message('debug', "error_log failed " . $The404s);
}
} else {
$msg2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ',404,2,page not set,SERVER_NAME,' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ',remote ip,' . (string)$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(!error_log( $msg2. "\n", 3, $The404s)) {
log_message('debug', "error_log failed " . $The404s);
}
}
```

I am 66, I started programming on IBM mainframes. I have written UNIX daemons and windows DLLs, but, I have never had to understand internet addressing.

My best guess is I could use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php, but, as I said, I don’t know how to validate my results

Anything you can tell me would be helpful.

I wrote my first program in 15 minutes. It took me 3 hours to keypunch it.
I wrote my first BASH script in 5 minutes. It took me a day to find out I had to put a . (period) in front of it to get it to execute.

Comment: I admire your tanacity. Unfortunately, CIDR would seem meaningless in your struggle - a CIDR is just a block of IP addresses  as defined by the people using that block - there is no way to correctly work out the size of the block remotely. ( a /24 is a reasonable arbitrary size. If you can get a full BGP feed - ie comprehensive lits of routes published between large routers) you could get see how big the block the ISP is advertising, but this likely will include multiple blocks.

Comment: In the early days of Internet, before CIDR (C implies classless), IP addresses from different ranges had different sizes, but that fell away about 30 years ago.

Comment: Thank you.  When you don't know how to formulate the question, it makes it hard to ask.  Given my example log and the offending IP I can get from:  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. If I want to stop 163.172.116.48, is this adequate.

Comment: In IPTABLES if you want to drop a single IP, you don't need to put in any netmask, and you don't need to worry about CIDR.  More generally (and I believe it will work with IPTABLES), you can specify a single IPv4 address by using a netmask of /32  (ie 255.255.255.255 = 1111111.111111.11111111.11111111 = 32  x 1)  Not sure if that helps?

Comment: Also, if you are wanting to block "bad" IP addresses, have you looked into Fail2Ban?  This can process log files as they are generated and can automatically block IP addresses based on log messages.  (It can also unban them after a given period) This would seem like a useful tool in your arsenal if you are trying to host WP sites and are looking for systems which are probing for common vulnerabilities.

Comment: Really awesome help thanks. I think davidgo answered my question, but, I still need clarification.  For my rules, which is better  iptables -A INPUT -s 5.9.77.102 -j DROP?  or  iptables -A INPUT -s 5.9.77.102/24 -j DROP or  iptables -A INPUT -s 5.9.77.102/32 -j DROP??  Should I add nothing, /24 or /32

Comment: The iptables command to block 172.16.2.2. would be "/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 172.16.2.2 -j DROP" - if you only want to prevent access to HTTP, you could use "/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 172.168.2.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP".

Comment: You should not add any netmask.  If you add /32 its the same as not adding a netmask.  If you use  5.9.77.102/24 that does not make sense in context of iptables, because a /24 blocks 256 addresses - so the correct version would be -s 5.9.77.0/24

Comment: If you are working remotely and/or on automated tools, you should add -p tcp  --dport 80 (and another one for port 443) as you can easily lock yourself out the box.   At least that way you will be able to get back in on port 22.  If its your local box, not adding a port will give you very marginally better security.

Comment: Dear davidgo.  I accept this as the answer. In IPTABLES if you want to drop a single IP, you don't need to put in any netmask, and you don't need to worry about CIDR.  If I want to block 5.9.77.102 use this  iptables -A INPUT -s 5.9.77.102 -j DROP  I I wanted to block all the IP addresses between 5.9.77.0 to   5.9.77.255   use this 5.9.77.0/24.  I hope that is accurate.  I believe you get reputation points if you answer the question.  If you want to put the answer in to get the points, please do and I will mark it as answered.  Big Thanks. Mucho Grande Grazie